# Add a method to invoked in another method that is compiled

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure this out: I have a compiled class file named A.class that has method `A()`.  I have another class file that I can edit called B.class that contains method `B()`.  I can't edit class A, and I need to invoke method `B()` when method `A()` is invoked, as if method `A()` calls method `B()`.

Comment: Can we have that in multiple sentences? Possibly with diagrams?

Comment: Please place the code that you have written for better understanding.

Comment: It is compulsory to make obj of  A..? or You are able to make obj of any class..?

Answer (score 0):

You can create class C which extends class A, and then override the method in A, but call the superclass method first.

```
public class C extends A {

    void myMethod() {
        super.myMethod();
        b.method();
    }
}
```

All other classes that use class A will have to be changed to use class C.

Comment: But that way means that when method A is called in class A the method A in class C won't get called. Right know I'm looking at https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/aop.chapt.html

Comment: That's why I mentioned that "All other classes that use class A will have to be changed to use class C."

Comment: Missed that, but I can't edit any other classes then class B.